# Keras flow_from_directory is messing up labels

Tags: keras

I'm loading batches of images in a keras generator. The directory has the following structure :

```
alot/
  1/
    1_c1i.png
    1_c1l1.png
    1_c1L1r60.png
    ...
  2/
    2_c1i.png
    2_c1l1.png
    ...
...
```

Each directory corresponds to a class, and contains 100 images. When I load them into a generator, it seems to mess up completely the labels the images belong to.

```
image_size_x = 200
image_size_y = 200

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'D:/wrkfldr/dataset_textures/alot',  
        batch_size=32,
        target_size=(image_size_x,image_size_y),
        class_mode='categorical')
```

If I iterate through the images, the label shown with each plot is wrong

```
x,y = train_generator.next()
for i in range(0,31):
    image = x[i]
    label = y[i]
    index = list(label).index(1)
    print (index)
    plt.imshow(image.reshape(image_size_x,image_size_y,3).astype(np.uint8))
    plt.show()
```

I have checked, there is not an offset of 1, or -1, or anything. The labels are really completely random, I have no idea why this is happening.

I have tried with an other structure, and it works. But this particular one doesn't, I have no clue why. Is there something obvious I'm missing ?

Comment: Please show us the labels that are produced and the labels you expect, there is nothing obviously wrong in the code you are showing.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, it's OK I fixed it. Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fantastic.

From the beginning, for a reason I cannot get my head around with, python was not classing the folders by incrementing number, but with some mix of concatenating numbers or wathever.

If I run

```
import os

    path = 'D:/wrkfldr/dataset_textures/alot'
    i = 0
    for _dir in os.listdir(path):

        print('%s %d' % (_dir,i))
        i += 1
```

The result is

```
1
10
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
11
110
111
112
113
114
115
```

So obviously, my labels were totally off because the CSV I used for the label was made such as the first line stands for the 0, the second is for the 1, the third is for the 2, and so on, not some doubtful concatenating stuff.

Anyway, I changed my folders name to the real class, and everything is OK.